# Is "Though tired he was, he played well" correct?

Tags: conjunctions

So I was searching on the internet to look for how to use "although" and "though." Then I saw a page that said "Though tired he was, he played well." 
Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Perhaps it has been altered by the author for poetic purposes.  The normal way to say it would be "Though he was tired, he played well."

Comment: "Tired as he was, he... " or "Though he was tired, he...". Though is a conjunction and it requires "subject + verb" after it.

Comment: It's certainly acceptable in most registers.  It's kind of like "Yoda-speak", and is typically used to achieve a "poetic" tone.

Comment: It’s something Tolkien might have written. It has an archaic and poetic ring to it, as Hot Licks says. If you switch the first two words around, you’ll get a more natural-sounding sentence: “Tired though he was, he played well”.

Comment: It becomes slightly more natural to invert the participle/verb order if you say. *He played well, though tired he was.* Also if you add a qualifier to the verb it becomes more acceptable  either way eg. *Though tired he undoubtedly was, he played well*

Answer (score 1):

> Though tired he was, he played well.

This is not a usual way of expressing this idea, and fluent speakers may find it odd. More usual ways would include:

> - Although he was tired, he played well.
> - Though he was tired, he played well.
> - Tired as he was, he played well.
> - In spite of being tired, he played well.
> - Despite being tired, he played well.

Yet other forms might change the second clause to "he still played well".

The example uses a device known as [*inverted syntax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics)), This refers to sentences (or phrases) where the normal order of words is altered. Here the adjective "tired" has been swapped with the verb phrase 'he was". This tends to give an old-fashioned, archaic feel to the expression. In verse, it is sometimes used to make the meter or rhyme work.

The [*Britannica* article "Inversion"](https://www.britannica.com/art/inversion-literature) refers to it as:

> the placing of an adjective after the noun it modifies (“the form divine”), a verb before its subject (“Came the dawn”), or a noun preceding its preposition (“worlds between”). Inversion is most commonly used in poetry in which it may both satisfy the demands of the metre and achieve emphasis.

Pecks ["Some Secrets of Syntax"](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/pep/index-eng.html?lang=eng&page=clarity_5_some_secrets_syntax) gives the example of

> My heart you have broken; my resolve you have cemented.

and observes that:

> Inversion is one of the simplest ways to vary syntax, but also one of the most dramatic. It’s best reserved for material that can handle some extra flair: literary, creative, dramatic or promotional documents, or material that will be read for entertainment as much as for content.

When used as a literary device, inversion is also known as "*anastrophe*"

See also:

- ["What are inversion and syntax?"](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/z4jf6g8/articles/zjsr47h) from the BBC
- ["Inverted Syntax: Definition & Examples"](https://study.com/academy/lesson/inverted-syntax-definition-examples.html) from study.com
- ["inversion"](https://literarydevices.net/inversion/) from *Literary Devices*

Answer (score 0):

> *"Though tired he was, he played well."*

No, it's not correct, because after *though* (which is called a "subordinate conjunction"), you should use **subject + verb [+ adjective]**, not **adjective + subject + verb**.

> Though he was tired, he played well.

There's another option, by the way:

> Tired as he was, he played well.

Comment: Hi, aparente. Can you include some reasons why it's not correct? I think your answer received a downvote because there is no *reason why it is not correct*. Do let me know when you edit your answer.

Comment: @Rathony - I used to teach English as a second language.  I still try to help my German spouse.  I think and teach in terms of pattern recognition -- showing people the correct pattern.  However, I would invite you to add some more theoretical rationale to my answer, or write an answer of your own, and then I'd be happy to delete mine.  (I'm pretty much self-taught in terms of grammar and usage.)

Comment: I've just edited your answer. Please take a look.

Comment: @Rathony - Very helpful, thank you.  I have edited it to make it fit my presentation style.  Hope it still holds water.

Comment: -1 It is certainly not the usual way of expressing this idea, the inverted syntax is often found in archaic or old-fashioned  texts, or is used for poetic effect. None of that makes it incorrect, however. I think the "rule" you specify (without a source) would be better described as a guideline or a usual practice, not an absolute rule.

Comment: I should add that "Tired though he was, he played well." is also correct.